# Group signature Elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature

I have been doing some research in group and ring signature literature. 
I am trying to find a ring/group signature which provide the following propriety:

- Anonymity for the signer
- Verifiable by a group manager
- Signer in the group should be able to create the signature on their own
- The construction should be based on elliptic curve

I have checked the AOS ring signature, which are almost what I need but unfortunately I didn't find a way to add a group manager or something like that.
Are AOS signature modifiable with a group manager ? Otherwise is there a scheme/research which has those proprieties?

Comment: Would you clarify "list item"? Or is that just the template that SE provided you? Is a "pure" ring signature enough; i.e., is spontaneous group forming allowed, and can it be verifiable by people outside the group?

Comment: The SE added  'List item', I'm not sure about its meaning. Pure ring signature are good (anonymous, spontaneous and verifiable) but they miss the fact that a third party can find out who is the real signer in the group.

Comment: Okay, please remove "List item" from your post then (edit your post). "find out who is the real signer in the group", you want to be able to leak/reveal the signer?

Comment: @RubenDeSmet Feel free to remove "List item" yourself next time. It is added if you create an empty list or a list with an empty bullet. Note that there is an additional question in the above comment, fraccaman.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the AOS-signature? It allows each member of a group to sign a message on it's own without revealing it's identity.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you, next time Ill edit myself :) So, if my understanding of AOS signature is correct, the scheme let you verify that someone has signed the message without knowing who is the real signer. That's fine cause I need anyone to able to prove that at least a signer, signed the message. What AOS don't let me do, is let a group manager be able to understand who is the real signer. That's basically my question.

Comment: @RubenDeSmet Yes, I would like go to be able to reveal the signer. But only a designated third party has to be able to reveal the signer. (I'm not sure but I think I'm looking for accountable ring signature)